# SQL Server: Index columns used in like?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, indexing

Is it a good idea to index varchar columns only used in LIKE opertations? From what I can read from query analytics I get from the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM ClientUsers WHERE Email LIKE '%niels@bosmainter%'
```

I get an "Estimated subtree cost" of 0.38 without any index and 0.14 with an index. Is this a good metric to use for anlayzing if a query has been optimized with an index?

Comment: This is very problematic when searching large tables with a data tables type scenario where all coloumns need to do a .contains search

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Given the data 'abcdefg'

```
WHERE Column1 LIKE '%cde%'  --can't use an index

WHERE Column1 LIKE 'abc%' --can use an index

WHERE Column1 Like '%defg' --can't use an index, but see note below
```

Note: If you have important queries that require '%defg', you could use a persistent computed column where you REVERSE() the column and then index it.  Your can then query on:

```
WHERE Column1Reverse Like REVERSE('defg')+'%' --can use the persistent computed column's index
```

Comment: I like your solution, though I'd call it an ugly hack ;)

Comment: I've used this ugly hack on a system where the original designer made numbers char(x) with leading zeros and other keys letter+ leading zeros.  try telling users they have to enter in the leading zeros and or letter+ leading zeros! ha. they want to enter in 203, not G000000203, so this reverse() "hack" will help there.

Comment: @KM. referenced this answer here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/91340/1-hour-query-is-there-another-way-to-do-this/91346#91346

Comment: I wouldn't call it a hack but a very nice solution.

Comment: It's a **beautiful** ugly hack

Comment: Not working like me expect.
Ex: I want search "have" in "I have a machine".
And not working

Answer (score 15):

In my experience the first %-sign will make any index useless, but one at the end will use the index.

Comment: Close enough - LIKE will use the prefix on an index but you can't resolve a wildcard through an index so that's as far as it will go.

Comment: So yay or nay for indexes on these columns?

Comment: If you always query the column with a leading %, the index will never be used. The answer thus depends on how you query your data.

Comment: **NOT COMPLETELY TRUE**, you _CAN_ hit an index on queries that use _LIKE '%xyz'_, but you need to do a little extra work, see my answer for an explanation

Answer (score 9):

To answer the metrics part of your question: The type of index/table scan/seek being performed is a good indicator for knowing if an index is being (properly) used. It's usually shown topmost in the query plan analyzer.

The following scan/seek types are sorted **from worst** (top) **to best** (bottom):

- Table Scan
- Clustered Index Scan
- Index Scan
- Clustered Index Seek
- Index Seek

As a rule of thumb, you would normally try to get seeks over scans whenever possible. As always, there are exceptions depending on table size, queried columns, etc. I recommend doing a [search on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=scan+seek+index) for "scan seek index", and you'll get a lot of good information about this subject.