# How can I optimize/refactor a TSQL "LIKE" clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, optimization, sql-like

I have a table with 117000 or so records. I need to perform a search that checks 3 separate fields for a given string pattern.

My where clause is as follows:

```
field1 LIKE '%' + @DESC + '%'
OR field2 LIKE '%' + @DESC + '%'
OR field3 LIKE '%' + @DESC + '%'
```

This seems to take about 24 seconds regardless of input...

Is there a better way to do this? Less than 10 (or 5!) seconds would be much more preferable.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use Full Text Search and [CONTAINS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx). LIKE cannot be optimized when searching in the middle of the field, ie. when the LIKE expression starts with an '%', so it will always do a full table scan.

Comment: you can use an index, with a little work, when doing LIKE '%'+string, see the link in my other comment.

Comment: @KM: Interesting trick, a reversed column. Also good analogy with the phone book, makes the case vividly clear.

Comment: nice trick , to obad there isn't anything similar for the like '%text%' problem.

Comment: @KM: It definitely has to be a '%test%' form, so the reverse method is out, though I have seen that before and it's a clever trick.  
I will have to try the Full Text Search, but it looks like I'm going to have to convince the DBAs to index it properly. Thank you for the suggestion. I will see if Full Text/Contains boosts performance.  
I recall doing this on the old database with the exact same query and it was much faster...not sure what the new one is doing differently

Comment: After getting the DBA's to Full Text Index the tables, this brought me down to 1-3 seconds for a search. Thanks for the help!

Comment: how about searching at the beginning of the string?

Comment: What if the parameter passed is null?

Comment: This is incorrect, LIKE can be optimized even when searching in the middle of the field. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/dwainsql/2014/03/26/getting-an-index-seek-to-speed-up-like-string-searches/

Comment: @Mr.TA narrowing a rowset for purpose of smaller fullscan is not an *index optimization*. Since you are insisting on reviving a 9 years old answer, you could at least look at a modern alternative like columnstore...

Comment: @RemusRusanu 1, I did not say `LIKE` is the only, or the preferred, solution. 2, did you read the page I linked? It shows how to use an index, not how to narrow a rowset, whatever that means.

Answer (score 3):

Anytime you start a LIKE search with a wildcard, you're doing a scan.  Unless you can narrow your search criteria to include the first character (which may not be feasible), you'll need to resort to Full Text Search.

Comment: @Stuart Ainsworth said _Anytime you start a LIKE search with a wildcard, you're doing a scan_, that soes not have to be true, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388059/sql-server-index-columns-used-in-like/1395881#1395881

Comment: Now you're just playing with semantics; you REVERSE the column and index it, and then reverse the like clause so it doesn't start with a wildcard.  You're not starting a search with a wildcard, so therefore you're not doing a scan.

I will admit that is an interesting solution, and I'll have to keep it in mind.

Comment: This is incorrect, LIKE can be optimized even when searching in the middle of the field. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/dwainsql/2014/03/26/getting-an-index-seek-to-speed-up-like-string-searches/

Comment: So nearly 8 years later, I learned something new :)  Never thought about removing the NULL values from a wildcard string search.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to start with a wildcard? Why? Often you can force users to type in the first character at least.  I bring this up becasue some developers just use the wildcard as a habit not becasue there is a requirement. In most cases users will be able to type the first character unless the filed stores long strings (like say official airport names).  Otherwise you really need to use full-text indexing although KM's trick with the reverse is pretty cool if you don't need the wildcard at the end.

If you can avoid doing the performance killing things, then do so.

Comment: Yes, I do need a double sided wildcard for this query. I need to find something like 'banana' in 'Strawberry Banana Yogurt.'

Answer (score 1):

Whilst I agree with the accepted answer that Full Text Indexing would be the best solution and am by no means advocating the use of leading wildcard searches if they have to be performed then there *are* potential steps that can be taken to make the performance of them less bad.

Kalen Delaney in the book "[Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Internals](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Microsoft-SQL-Server-2008-Internals/dp/0735626243)" says:

> Collation can make a huge difference
>   when SQL Server has to look at almost
>   all characters in the strings. For
>   instance, look at the following:
>
> ```
> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl WHERE longcol LIKE '%abc%'
> ```
>
> This may execute 10 times faster or more with a binary collation than a nonbinary Windows collation. And with `varchar` data, this executes up to seven or eight times faster with a SQL collation than with a Windows collation.

Comment: More from the book "If you have a varchar column, you can speed this up
by forcing the collation as follows:
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl
WHERE longcol COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP_CI_AS LIKE '%abc%';"

Comment: @yoelhalb you probably meant `_CP1_` not `_CP_`

Answer (score 1):

I tried one possible solution. Before this solution even query was not returning result and causing connection timeout error.

My query was having date filter and other criteria. All other criteria was like search. One column keyword was searching like '%abc%' on ntext column and it was doing full table scan.

Solution:

Divide query in 2 parts. 1) First part in CTE (Common Table Express) 2) Apply all search criteria on CTE.

```
WITH SearchData(Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4,........)
    AS
    (
    SELECT Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4,...........
    FROM myTable1 WITH(NOLOCK) 
            INNER JOIN MyTable2 WITH(NOLOCK) 
                ON MyTable1.id = MyTable2.Id
    WHERE (MyTable1.CreationTime >= '2014-04-27' AND MyTable1.CreationTime <= '2014-05-01') 
 )

    SELECT DISTINCT top 250 Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4
    FROM SearchData
    WHERE   (ISNULL(Column1,'') LIKE @Column1  +'%' OR @Column1 IS NULL)
            and (Column2 LIKE @Column2+ '%' OR @Column2 IS NULL)
            ...
            ...
            ...
            ...
            AND (Column10 like '%'+@Column10+'%' or @Column10 IS NULL)
            AND @Column1+@Column2+@Column3+........@Column10 <> ''  
            ORDER BY [CreationTime] DESC
```

It worked for me.

Comment: I think using `TOP` clause with a query that has a LIKE condition will always up the performance. So its the TOP clause rather than a CTE that contributes to performance gain, since with TOP a full scan is cut short as soon as the required number of records is scanned.

Comment: as a off-topic note using WITH(NOLOCK) in every join is very dangerous you must be very careful with it or you will get duplicated data etc... I see people trowing this hint as a standard way of optimizing queries, its not. you should always think twice and review the way tables are written (inserted/update) in your application before trowing in a nolock hint. (just saying)

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use FullTextSearch you can increase speed in 10 times. Do next:

1 Add calculated field:

```
alter table TableName
add CalculatedColumnName as upper(Column1 + '|' + Column2...) collate Latin1_General_100_Bin2
persisted;
```

2 Add index for calculated field:

```
create nonclustered index IDX_TableName_CalculatedColumnName
on TableName(CalculatedColumnName);
```

3 Change your query text

```
select count(*)
from TableName
where CalculatedColumnName like '%' + upper(@ParameterValue) + '%' collate Latin1_General_100_Bin2
```

Source: http://aboutsqlserver.com/2015/01/20/optimizing-substring-search-performance-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
field1 + field2 + field3 LIKE '%' + @DESC + '%'
```

or

```
CONTAINS(field1 + field2 + field3, @DESC)
```