# Performance of like '%Query%' vs full text search CONTAINS query

Tags: sql, database, performance, full-text-search, sql-like

I have a situation where I would like to **search a single word**.

For that scenario, which query would be good from a performance point of view?

```
Select Col1, Col2 from Table Where Col1 Like '%Search%'
```

or

```
Select Col1, Col2 from Table Where Col1 CONTAINS(Col1,'Search')
```

?

Comment: I would also be interested in knowing: what is the relative performance of a query using `REGEXP` for the same purpose?

Comment: What database? They will have entirely different performance characteristics in different databases.

Comment: @Oded: MS-SQL Server and MySQL are the two I use most. For the purposes of the question, I assume SQL Server is of most interest.

Comment: @dotnetguts can you provide me a link where i can read about CONTAINS proper usage...so far all i know is A CONTAINS B means A is superset of B.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Full Text Searching (using the CONTAINS) will be faster/more efficient than using LIKE with wildcarding.  Full Text Searching (FTS) includes the ability to define Full Text Indexes, which FTS can use. I don't know why you wouldn't define a FTS index if you intended to use the functionality.

LIKE with wildcarding on the left side (IE: `LIKE '%Search'`) can not use an index (assuming one exists for the column), guaranteeing a table scan.  I haven't tested & compared, but regex has the same pitfall.  To clarify, `LIKE '%Search'` and `LIKE '%Search%'` can **not** use an index; `LIKE 'Search%'` can use an index.

Comment: In MS SQL Server, a full text index is required in order to use CONTAINS.

Comment: Is it going to be faster than full text search engines.. like Lucene / Solr? Especially in case of millions of records.

Answer (score 7):

For a typical database, the CONTAINS search can be much faster assuming the appropriate full text search index is built on the field being searched.  The evaluation of the `LIKE` operator  generally doesn't use an index and thus must read all the data.

Answer (score -2):

Like search on Table it self, will kill the performance. 
Better to apply like search on CTE.

Comment: try below url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569002/how-can-i-optimize-refactor-a-tsql-like-clause/32329298#32329298