# What mysql indexes should I use with this query?

Tags: mysql, linux, indexing, key

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE caption LIKE 'name%' AND type = 'private' OR owner LIKE 'name%' type = 'private' ORDER BY uses DESC LIMIT 40;
```

Possible keys: items_caption,items_owner,items_type
Key: items_uses
(Got these by using the explain command)

It takes about 1.8 seconds to do that query and there are over million records in the table. I don't know how to make a index for this query and I've no control over the source so I can't modify the query.

Comment: what is the missing operator between `LIKE 'name%'` and `type = 'private'`

Comment: Oops. It's AND.  SELECT * FROM items WHERE caption LIKE 'name%' AND type = 'private' OR owner LIKE 'name%' AND type = 'private' ORDER BY uses DESC LIMIT 40;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've got at select *, you can't really do a covering index, but you could do a pair of composite indexes on (caption,type) and (owner, type).

```
ALTER TABLE items ADD INDEX (caption, type);
ALTER TABLE items ADD INDEX (owner, type);
```

This should cut down on internal point lookups.

I don't think you need fulltext search since the value you're comparing with your LIKE's do not start with a wildcard (%).  Likes that compare with strings not starting with % can use traditional fast b-tree indexes.  If you have a % at the start of the LIKE as in '%name' this wouldn't be the case.

Also, don't forget the conditions your searching are:

> caption LIKE 'name%' AND type = 'private'

OR

> owner LIKE 'name%' AND type = 'private'

So "ADD FULLTEXT(caption,owner)" won't help much if the caption clause fails and it tries to lookup by owner and type.

Comment: Thanks. It is a lot faster now (took 0.031 seconds)

Comment: I've noticed more problems with the query now. When there's query like `SELECT * FROM items WHERE caption LIKE '_name_%' AND type = 'private' OR owner LIKE '_name_%' and type = 'private' ORDER BY uses DESC LIMIT 40; ` It isn't using any indexes. Just because the name is between the underscores. Why is this happening and is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @user1563934 run `show create table <tablename>` and add the result to the post so I can see your table structure.   The underscore should not affect anything unless you put a '%' before it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do fulltext indexing on 'caption' and it will increase the query time significantly.

```
ALTER TABLE items ADD FULLTEXT(caption,owner);
```

Mysql v 5.6 and above support fulltext search in innodb.
https://blogs.oracle.com/MySQL/entry/full_text_search_with_innodb

Comment: I'm using innodb so I think it's not possible. I forgot to mention it sorry.

Comment: Actually in newer version of mysql support fulltext search in innodb databse. https://blogs.oracle.com/MySQL/entry/full_text_search_with_innodb

Comment: As I also failed to realize, OP can't modify the query so a fulltext will do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a [explain](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) query first to see how is it working.  We can't help you if we don't know how is the query being execute and the structure of your table. I.E, @chheplo says that you can add index on your text search

```
ALTER TABLE items ADD FULLTEXT(caption,owner);
```

But it will depend to your DB design, if you are using Mysql 5.6- and your engine is Innodb it wont work, you'll need engine = MyISAM, to be able to create text index, also you need to execute the explain to see if the select is also using it.  However I think if you avoid the "LIKE" it will be faster, [Performance of like '%Query%' vs full text search CONTAINS query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213998/performance-of-like-query-vs-full-text-search-contains-query)

Regards