# MySql query taking too much time, While all columns are indexed

Tags: mysql, optimization, query-optimization

Below query is taking more then 30 seconds to fetch 10 records.

```
        SELECT
        `u`.*,`f`.`functional_area`,`f`.`is_active` AS `is_ft_active`,`pe`.`title`,`pe`.`company`,
    (
        SELECT
            cv_file
        FROM
            profile_cvs
        WHERE
            profile_cvs.user_id = u.id AND profile_cvs.is_active = 1 AND deleted_at IS NULL
        ORDER BY
            profile_cvs.id
        DESC
    LIMIT 1
    ) AS cv_file
    FROM
        `users` AS `u`
    LEFT JOIN `functional_areas` AS `f` ON `f`.`id` = `u`.`functional_area_id`
    LEFT JOIN `profile_experiences` AS `pe` ON `pe`.`user_id` = `u`.`id`
    LEFT JOIN `profile_cvs` AS `pc` ON `pc`.`user_id` = `u`.`id`
    LEFT JOIN `profile_summaries` AS `ps` ON `ps`.`user_id` = `u`.`id`
    LEFT JOIN `profile_educations` AS `ped` ON `ped`.`user_id` = `u`.`id`
    LEFT JOIN `profile_skills` AS `psk` ON `psk`.`user_id` = `u`.`id`
    LEFT JOIN `job_skills` AS `js` ON `js`.`id` = `psk`.`job_skill_id`
    LEFT JOIN `admins` AS `ad` ON `ad`.`id` = `u`.`created_by`
    WHERE
                (`js`.`job_skill` IN("HVAC")) OR(`f`.`functional_area` LIKE "%HVAC %") OR(`u`.`search` LIKE "%HVAC%") OR(`ps`.`summary` LIKE "% HVAC%") OR(`ped`.`degree_title` LIKE "HVAC")
            
    GROUP BY
        `u`.`id`
    ORDER BY  CASE WHEN
js.job_skill LIKE '%HVAC %' THEN 1 ELSE 0
END + CASE WHEN f.functional_area LIKE '%HVAC %' THEN 1 ELSE 0
END + CASE WHEN ps.summary LIKE '% HVAC%' THEN 1 ELSE 0
END + CASE WHEN u.search LIKE '% HVAC %' THEN 1 ELSE 0
END
DESC
,
        `u`.`is_blocked` ASC,
        `js`.`job_skill` DESC,
        `f`.`functional_area` DESC,
        `u`.`search` DESC,
        `u`.`id` DESC
    LIMIT 10;
```

We checked every column is indexed, which is used in this query. Also user table has less then 1,00,000 records.
So please explain why this query is taking too much time.

Update 1:-
Here is the explanation of the above query:-

[image: Explantion]

Comment: Your like conditions cannot use an index as they all have % prefix, so your where and order by clauses both rely on full table scans to filter out and sort data. I'm not sure you can optimise these problems away, unless you can replace the like with exact searches. This may require redesign of your database structure.

Comment: We changed like % with regexp, But still taking 15 seconds.

Comment: String search with like and two wildcards are going to be slow and won't benefit greatly from indexing, https://stackoverflow.com/a/11795857/18423808. You're doing it more than 5 times, in the queries current state it will never run fast (with or without indexing). Look to modify the query to minimize string comparisons or go the stored procedure route.

Comment: @IndexZero now we replaced our LIKE keyword with  regexp '(^|[[:space:]])HVAC([[:space:]]|$)')   , But now its still taking 15 seconds.

Comment: @pankajagarwal regex cannot use indexes either.

Comment: @Shadow So how we can make this query faster?

Comment: You have to get rid of the searching within the field condition by restructuring your data.