# CONTAINS Not Working in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am working with CONTAINS, but it is not woking in mysql.

> ```
>  mysql> SELECT * FROM MUTHU;
> +---------------------+
> | MY                  |
> +---------------------+
> | how is your studies |
> | how are you there   |
> | hi there            |
> +---------------------+
> 3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
> ```

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM MUTHU CONTAINS ( MY, "how" );
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '( MY,
 "how" )' at line 1
```

Comment: Is `CONTAINS` even a real MySQL function, I couldn't find anything about it on their documentation. :S

Answer (score 1):

I don't think MYSQL has a function called `CONTAINS`, try the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM MUTHU
WHERE MY LIKE '%how%';
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213998/performance-of-like-query-vs-full-text-search-contains-query

Comment: Mysql has keyword CONTAINS. Please edit your answer.

Comment: @AbhimanyuAryan Please can you tell me where are documentations on `CONTAINS` keyword???

Comment: This was confusing for me as well. It looks like CONTAINS is not available for MySQL, only other databases like MS SQL.

Answer (score 1):

I believe contains is used primarily in Xpath/Xquery. A similar function in mysql is INSTR(). The proper code is for using this is:

```
    select * from MUTHU
    where INSTR(MY, 'how') > 0;
```

Comment: @EAGER_STUDENT in response to your question below, the answer is you'll have to call INSTR twice. like so: where (INSTR(MY, 'how') > 0) or (INSTR(MY, 'hello') > 0 );

Answer (score 0):

you missed the `Where` condition,

try this:

```
SELECT * FROM MUTHU
Where MY CONTAINS ( MY,"how" );
```

Comment: But I want query like select * from MUTHU
    where INSTR(MY, 'how' OR 'hello') ; Is there any way?