# Can you use DOES NOT CONTAIN in SQL to replace not like?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, full-text-search

I have a table called `logs.lognotes`, and I want to find a faster way to search for customers who do not have a specific word or phrase in the note.  I know I can use "not like", but my question is, can you use `DOES NOT CONTAINS` to replace not like, in the same way you can use:

```
SELECT *
  FROM table
 WHERE CONTAINS (column, ‘searchword’)
```

Comment: just use `not contains`

Comment: It is just "NOT CONTAINS" I believe I hope this helps.

Comment: What makes you think it's faster?

Comment: @PM77-1 it is faster. `CONTAINS` can only be used on columns with a `FULL TEXT INDEX` on and can take advantage of the index, whereas `LIKE` with two wildcard operators cannot use indices. This is confirmed on [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx) and in at least one other [stackoverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7510685/1048425)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you should be able to use `NOT` on any boolean expression, as mentioned in the SQL Server Docs [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189455(v=sql.100).aspx). And, it would look something like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM table
 WHERE NOT CONTAINS (column, ‘searchword’)
```

To search for records that do not contain the 'searchword' in the column. And, according to

[Performance of like '%Query%' vs full text search CONTAINS query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213998/performance-of-like-query-vs-full-text-search-contains-query)

this method should be faster than using `LIKE` with wildcards.

Answer (score 1):

You can also simply use this:

```
select * from tablename where not(columnname like '%value%')
```

Comment: I used this instead of the CONTAINS method below because the table was not full text indexed