# Query optimizer in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, query-optimization

We have the following code:

```
select * from View1 where (Timestamp >= @x) and (SomeCode like 'ABC%')
```

It runs **terribly slow**. But the code

```
select * from View1 where (Timestamp >= @x)      (*)
```

runs **pretty fast**. Also `SomeCode like...` filter runs pretty fast on the previous (*) code. So, it's fast when two-phased. (`View1` is a CLR computed view.)

**Question**: how to advice SQL Server 2008 R2 to make the query (more precisely, the two filters) in two phases, that is, first the `Timestamp` filter and then the `SomeCode` filter.

**Note**: Nesting the queries doesn't work for us, it's slow as well.

Comment: Is `View1` indexed? If not, are the tables underlying `View1` indexed?

Comment: and what does `(*)` mean in a `where` clause?

Comment: (*) is a label in the text, not SQL.

Comment: Indexes won't help: LIKE alwasy has to do a full table scan.

Comment: What is a "CLR Computed View" http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=CLR+Computed+View&oq=CLR+Computed+View&gs_l=hp.3...1203.6188.0.6594.17.15.0.2.2.0.281.2421.1j11j3.15.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.57XFV1eLfCk&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=f7f26bd304355f44&bpcl=35466521&biw=1280&bih=841&safe=active

Comment: @egrunin, that is not correct.  Using a `starts with` like will allow you to use indexes.  If he were doing a `contains` or `ends with` like you would be correct.

Comment: @egrunin http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388059/sql-server-index-columns-used-in-like

Comment: @egrunin - Not true. If the `LIKE` is used without the `%`, then an index can be used, cause is identical to an `=` (`WHERE a LIKE 'hello'`), it may even use an index if the first part is missing an `%` (`WHERE a LIKE 'hello%'`)

Comment: I misspoke: *wildcards* - which his example uses - force a table scan.

Comment: @egrunin - And then, it should be *wildcards at the beggining of the string* force a table scan

Comment: @egrunin: again: **NO**. Since it's a `LIKE 'ABC%'` **without** a leading `%` - an index on that column **will definitely** be used - if it makes sense. `LIKE` is only bad when using leading `%` - `LIKE '%ABC%'` would be horribly bad...

Comment: @marc_s : very clear. I'll leave my erroneous remarks in as an example for others to see :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There are probably better ways, but this one works for me:

```
SELECT * from (SELECT * FROM View1 WHERE Timestamp >= @x) x
WHERE field_x LIKE 'ABC%'
```

This forces the fast query to be run first.

*Responding to the comments:*

Maybe "force" isn't the right word, but I've definitely observed it making a difference. I'll revise this if someone has a better suggestion.

**Responding to your comment:**

"Doesn't work" = still slow?

In which case: is the Timestamp column indexed? Is SQL Server running short on resources (memory, disk space) with the larger query? Have you looked at the execution plan?

What happens if you *really* force the issue:

```
SELECT * into #tmp FROM View1 WHERE Timestamp >= @x
SELECT * from #tmp WHERE field_x LIKE 'ABC%'
```

Comment: Using the first filter as a derived table doesn't *force* that query to be run first, the optimizer will choose the best way to run this query

Comment: It runs slow, yes. Memory, disk -- everything is fine.

Comment: @egrunin: I've already written that, when split, it runs FAST.