# MSSQL WHERE A.field1 IN B.field2 when field2 format is '11111','22222','33333','55555'

Tags: sql-server, in-clause

I have a weird issue to solve and I am not sure what would be the best way to do this from a performance perspective as I have millions of records to parse in table A (but only 1 row in table B per query). Table B is coming from a UI selectbox.

> TABLE A id nvarchar(10) contractnb nvarchar(8) -- '22222', otherflags
> = 'blue'
>
> TABLE B paramsid int contracts(255) --
> '11111','22222','4444444','5555555' otherflags nvarchar(5)

I need to

> SELECT * from A, B WHERE B.paramsid = 1  AND A.otherflags =
> B.otherflags AND A.contractnb IN B.contracts --THIS IS THE ISSUE

I was thinking to use LIKE and do something like this below but I think performance wise it is not a good idea :
AND (%A.contractnb%) LIKE B.contracts

But all of this is not working. Any help / input would be quite appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You are right, `LIKE` will perform horribly when used like that. This is one of many reasons a row should only have one value in each column. Fix the design, or you're stuck with terrible queries like this

Comment: I don't control the input. Unfortunately, this is often the life of a integration techie.

Comment: Considering you only have one row in B, you can normalize that row into a new (temporary) table

Comment: Evolve! No one should be using [old-style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: [How bad is storing a comma-delimited list in a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Comment: STRING_SPLIT seems to be doing the job and if performance is an issue I could indeed output it in a temp table before batch process

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

This can be made to work with LIKE as follows, but as mentioned in the comment it is not the most efficient solution. (If we're talking about a few hundred lines it's not going to be a problem.)
See the dbFiddle link at the bottom for creation of test schema.

> ```
> SELECT * FROM A;
> SELECT * FROM B;
> ```

> ```
> id | contractnb                    | otherflags
> :- | :---------------------------- | :---------
> 1  | 11111                         | blue      
> 2  | 22222                         | blue      
> 3  | 4444444                       | blue      
> 4  | 5555555                       | blue      
> 5  | 11111,22222,33333,44444,55555 | blue      
>
> paramsid | contracts | otherflags
> -------: | :-------- | :---------
>        1 | 22222     | blue
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * 
> from A
> JOIN B ON A.otherflags = B.otherflags 
> WHERE B.paramsid = 1 
> AND A.contractnb like CONCAT('%',B.contracts,'%');
> ```

> ```
> id | contractnb                    | otherflags | paramsid | contracts | otherflags
> :- | :---------------------------- | :--------- | -------: | :-------- | :---------
> 2  | 22222                         | blue       |        1 | 22222     | blue      
> 5  | 11111,22222,33333,44444,55555 | blue       |        1 | 22222     | blue
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=ca3b39fe9b21e405e36c4f8590f904ea)*

Answer (score 0):

if tableB is only one row, you can use a solution like this

```
insert into tableA values (1, 'blue', 22222)
insert into tableB values (1, '11111,22222,4444444,5555555', 'blue')
 
 
select b.otherflags,
       value,
       a.*
from   tableB b
  outer apply string_split(b.contracts, ',')
  left join tableA a on value = a.otherflags
where b.paramsid = 1
```

But when tableB can have many rows and performance is too bad, consider moving the data from tableB into another table which is normalized

[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=42de9c2ca05baf8c4245ac1366003c9d)

| otherflags | value | id | contractnb | otherflags_1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| blue | 11111 |  |  |  |
| blue | 22222 | 1 | blue | 22222 |
| blue | 4444444 |  |  |  |
| blue | 5555555 |  |  |  |

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can't use `IN` clause in this case because you have two strings but the `IN` works with lists of values:

```
'val1' IN ('val2', 'val3', 'val1')
```

For your question you can use `LIKE` and `CHARINDEX` with `COLLATION Latin1_General_BIN` option.

```
select * 
from A, B
where ',' + B.contracts + ',' collate Latin1_General_BIN like '%,' + A.contractnb + ',%' collate Latin1_General_BIN 

select * 
from A, B
where charindex(',' + A.contractnb + ',' collate Latin1_General_BIN, ',' + B.contracts + ',' collate Latin1_General_BIN)>0
```

This makes `LIKE` and `CHARINDEX` much more fast, but pay attention because it is a `CASE SENSITIVE` match.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37677204/using-sqlserver-contains-for-partial-words/38329568#38329568) for complete analysis.