# match & against to find a string in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have:

```
 ----------------------------
| ID          |  Workout     |
|_____________|______________|
| 1           |Chest workout |
| 2           |beach Workout |
| 3           |End workout   |
_____________________________
```

Basically I want to search a string in my `workout` column.

Now if you try `SELECT * FROM db.table WHERE MATCH (workout) AGAINST('workout');`
Or  `SELECT * FROM db.table WHERE MATCH (workout) AGAINST('Chest');` They Both works fine.

But If you try `SELECT * FROM db.table WHERE MATCH (workout) AGAINST('est');`

FYI: (est as in Chest) does not works even I have a row named `Chest` in my `workout` column.

So I would really appreciate if you tell how to select a string within a full text and within word and order them by characters first character like 1. end workout, 2. beach workout, 3. Chest workout in SQL.

Comment: can you use like ?

Comment: If your existing code works fine, then you are not using SQL Server.  I removed the tag.

Comment: I think you can switch off the short words setting

Comment: @krishnpatel Can you give me an example of like?

Comment: @Jaywardan there are already two ans

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wouldn't a `LIKE` statement do more of what you are looking for?
Something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table WHERE workout LIKE '%est%'
```

The query above should return anything that contains est.

Comment: That pretty much worked and can you tell me how to order them by characters first in word i mean like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE workout LIKE '%e%'` so it should order them like: 1. end workout, 2. beach workout, 3. Chest workout.

Comment: You should be able to use 'ORDER BY workout desc' or 'asc' depending on what direction you want to go.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't use `like`, as Gordon Linoff said it doesn't use indexes but my table rows are huge so I need an indexed way or a better way to find the string quicker. Do you know any better way from performance perspective?

Comment: @Jaywardan I believe that you can tune the performance of the like statement. [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388059/sql-server-index-columns-used-in-like has an excellent breakdown on how to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is that you seem to want:

```
where Workout like '%est%'
```

`'est'` is a substring, not a *word*.  That is a very important distinction when using full text indexes.  If you need to search for any string of characters, then `like` has the functionality.  `MATCH` is basically looking for words.

The unfortunate thing is that `like` won't use indexes in this case.  If you have a large amount of data, you might want to look for alternative technologies better suited to this problem.

Comment: Ohh what? My table rows is huge I need indexed way, you said other technologies can you give an example?

Comment: Postrgres has GIN and GIST indexes that can optimize `LIKE` queries.