# Reverse string with leading wildcard scan in Postgres

Tags: mysql, postgresql, indexing, pattern-matching, postgresql-performance

> [SQL Server: Index columns used in like?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388059/sql-server-index-columns-used-in-like)

I've tried using the query method in the link above with Postgres (0.3ms improvement), it seems to only work with MySQL (10x faster).

MYSQL

```
User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT * FROM users WHERE reverse_name LIKE REVERSE('%Anderson PhD')
User Load (5.8ms)  SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE ('%Anderson Phd')
```

POSTGRES

```
User Load (2.1ms)  SELECT * FROM users WHERE reverse_name LIKE REVERSE('%Scot Monahan')
User Load (2.5ms)  SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE '%Scot Monahan'
```

Did some googling but couldn't quite understand as I'm quite new to DBs. Could anyone explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To support a prefix match in Postgres for character type columns you either need an index with a suitable operator class: `text_pattern_ops` for text etc. (Unless you work with the "C" locale ...)

Or you use a trigram index to support *any* pattern - then you don't need the "reverse" trick any more.

See:

- [PostgreSQL LIKE query performance variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566717/postgresql-like-query-performance-variations/13452528#13452528)

You'll see *massive* performance improvement for tables of none-trivial size, as soon as an index can be used for the query. Have a look at the query plan with [`EXPLAIN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html).